# How to remove default open application

Tags: macos, launchpad

I have downloaded file `darwin_amd64` and occasionally chosen Text Edit as its default application. Now I cannot install it cause it always opens as text file.

Comment: What kind of file is it actually? Is `darwin_amd64` the full name or just the suffix? What does running `file FILENAME` in Terminal say?

Comment: What is it? What is the full filename? Where did you download it from?

Comment: You can right click on the file and pick your opener.

Comment: Are the executable flags set?

Answer (score 1):

If it is an executable, open Terminal.app, drag and drop the  file in the window and hit enter.

To change the default opener, right click on the file > get info > open with.